# Understanding window functions to deduplicate records while retaining true changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I asked this in dba stack exchange but haven't had any luck. Cross-posting.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/18cae/6)

I am close to figuring this out but I'm just stuck at a wall. I'm attempting to understand [a post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44784/trying-to-find-the-last-time-that-a-value-has-changed?noredirect=1&lq=1) by Aaron Betrand and apply it to a situation I've encountered where I have a changes table that's heavily duplicated due to prior design error I'm inheriting. The sample data set is identical in concept to my real data set, except SortOrder would usually be a datetime value and not an integer. 
The code I've tried is here:

```
; with main as (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID, Val, sortorder order by ID,
      SortOrder) as "Rank",
      row_number() over (partition by ID, val order by ID, sortorder) as "s_rank" 
   from 
      (values (1, 'A', 1), (1, 'A', 1), (1, 'B', 2), (1, 'C', 3), (1, 'B', 4),
              (1, 'A', 5), (1, 'A', 5), (2, 'A', 1), (2, 'B', 2), (2, 'A', 3), 
              (3, 'A', 1), (3, 'A', 1), (3, 'A', 2)
      ) as x("ID", "VAL", "SortOrder")
   group by id, val, SortOrder
   --order by ID, "SortOrder"
),
cte_rest as (
   select *
   from main
   where "s_rank" > 1
)

select *
from main
left join cte_rest rest
   on main.id = rest.id
   and main.s_rank > 1
   and main.SortOrder = rest.SortOrder
--where not exists (select 1 from cte_rest r where r.id = main.id and r.val <> main.VAL and main.s_rank < s_rank)
order by main.ID, main.SortOrder
```

The results are **almost** valid; however, the last row highlights a situation that I haven't been able to account for: the date changes, the value doesn't. **I want the last record to be excluded because it's not a true value change.**

```
╔════╦═════╦═══════════╦══════╦════════╦══════╦══════╦═══════════╦══════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ VAL ║ SortOrder ║ Rank ║ s_rank ║  ID  ║ VAL  ║ SortOrder ║ Rank ║ s_rank ║
╠════╬═════╬═══════════╬══════╬════════╬══════╬══════╬═══════════╬══════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ A   ║         1 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  1 ║ B   ║         2 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  1 ║ C   ║         3 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  1 ║ B   ║         4 ║    1 ║      2 ║ 1    ║ B    ║ 4         ║ 1    ║ 2      ║
║  1 ║ A   ║         5 ║    1 ║      2 ║ 1    ║ A    ║ 5         ║ 1    ║ 2      ║
║  2 ║ A   ║         1 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  2 ║ B   ║         2 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  2 ║ A   ║         3 ║    1 ║      2 ║ 2    ║ A    ║ 3         ║ 1    ║ 2      ║
║  3 ║ A   ║         1 ║    1 ║      1 ║ NULL ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║ NULL ║ NULL   ║
║  3 ║ A   ║         2 ║    1 ║      2 ║ 3    ║ A    ║ 2         ║ 1    ║ 2      ║
╚════╩═════╩═══════════╩══════╩════════╩══════╩══════╩═══════════╩══════╩════════╝
```

A colleague of mine suggested this code, and while I can follow how it arrives, I don't understand why the first code sample doesn't work. It feels to me like this would require a lot of extra parsing, and with a large data set I'd be worried about performance impacts.

```
WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT [id]
              , [val]
              , [sortorder]
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [id]
                                             , [val]
                                             , [sortorder]
                ORDER BY [id]
                       , [sortorder]) AS "rankall"
         FROM   (VALUES
                        ( 1, 'A', 1 ),
                        ( 1, 'A', 1 ),
                        ( 1, 'B', 2 ),
                        ( 1, 'C', 3 ),
                        ( 1, 'B', 4 ),
                        ( 1, 'A', 5 ),
                        ( 1, 'A', 5 ),
                        ( 2, 'A', 1 ),
                        ( 2, 'B', 2 ),
                        ( 2, 'A', 3 ),
                        ( 3, 'A', 1 ),
                        ( 3, 'A', 1 ),
                        ( 3, 'A', 2 )) AS x("id", "val", "sortorder")),
     ctedropped
     AS (SELECT [id]
              , [val]
              , [sortorder]
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [id]
                                             , [val]
                                             , [sortorder]
                ORDER BY [id]
                       , [sortorder]) AS "rankall"
         FROM   cte1
         WHERE  [cte1].[rankall] > 1)
     SELECT [cte1].[id]
          , [cte1].[val]
          , [cte1].[sortorder]
     FROM   cte1
     WHERE  NOT EXISTS
     (
         SELECT *
         FROM   [ctedropped]
         WHERE  [cte1].[id] = [ctedropped].[id] AND 
                [cte1].[val] = [ctedropped].[val] AND 
                [cte1].[rankall] = [ctedropped].[rankall]
     )
     ORDER BY [cte1].[id]
            , [cte1].[sortorder];
```

Comment: Would be nice to see a link to original post to find out what Aaron Betrand have said

Comment: @Alex thanks for noticing that, link has been added.

Comment: @Alex . . . It would be nice to see sample data and desired results.

Comment: Gordon, I provided that in the sql fiddle and the table, I thought. What additional information would help? Or just live data?

Comment: what is role of sortorder ? "the date changes, the value doesn't .." where is date in last or anywhere ? What is your core requirement like ?Do you want to know duplicate record or any change in record ?When there is any change in record then what date column do ?Forget your query for a while.

Comment: My requirement is to identify changes in records that constitute the value of the row, which may be a flag or a catcher column depending on the source, while eliminating erroneous duplicates. I inherited some bad logic that I fixed to stop inserting duplicate rows (so no more same ID, same value, same date rows are being added); however, the source of the data sometimes changes the equivalent of a last date modified field with no actual change on the record. I'm trying to clean those up as part of a redesign to prevent them from being logged in the future.

Comment: This being said, I was able to use the second query to achieve the desired results. My confusion comes from the first query not working. Query #2 first cte is basically a group by ID, VAL, SORTORDER and second cte gets rid of duplicate ID, VAL while resetting to allow reverts to a previous state to be kept.. which is what the first query does with the not exists clause that says not exists when IDs match, values are not the same, and the rank is lower - aka if I have ID 3, val A, sort 1, ID 3, val A, sort 2, because no 3 and <> A exists with a lower rank than my current rank, exclude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove rows where the value doesn't change you can apply this logic:

```
WITH cte1 AS
 (
   SELECT [id]
        , [val]
        , [sortorder]
        , Lag(val) Over(PARTITION BY [id]
                        ORDER BY [sortorder]) AS prevval
   FROM    demo
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte1
WHERE prevval IS NULL  -- first row
   OR prevval <> val   -- value changed
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/18cae/12)

Comment: This looks great. Dnoeth, do you happen to know why ordering by sortorder works without ordering by id?

Comment: @SeanBrookins You already PARTITION by id, thus all rows in a partition share the same id value.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the results you're getting *but only if the VAL has changed*.  Your query doesn't work because you have nothing in your query that accomplishes the *but*.  I think somewhere you can use lag() to make sure that the rest.VAL does not equal the previous row's main.VAL.  One idea -- you can add the previous value to the main CTE using lag and then use the previous VAL in your join criteria.  There are probably better/more elegant ways to do this.

```
; with main as (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID, Val, sortorder order by ID,
      SortOrder) as "Rank",
      row_number() over (partition by ID, val order by ID, sortorder) as "s_rank",
      lag(VAL,1) over (order by ID,sortorder) as prevVAL -- Here is the lag that populates the previous VAL
   from 
      (values (1, 'A', 1), (1, 'A', 1), (1, 'B', 2), (1, 'C', 3), (1, 'B', 4),
              (1, 'A', 5), (1, 'A', 5), (2, 'A', 1), (2, 'B', 2), (2, 'A', 3), 
              (3, 'A', 1), (3, 'A', 1), (3, 'A', 2)
      ) as x("ID", "VAL", "SortOrder")
   group by id, val, SortOrder
   --order by ID, "SortOrder"
),
cte_rest as (
   select *
   from main
   where "s_rank" > 1
)
select *
from main

left join cte_rest rest
   on main.id = rest.id
   and main.s_rank > 1
   and main.SortOrder = rest.SortOrder
   and rest.VAL <> main.prevVAL -- Here is where we make sure there is a change in VAL
 --where not exists (select 1 from cte_rest r where r.id = main.id and r.val <> main.VAL and main.s_rank < s_rank)
order by main.ID, main.SortOrder
```

Comment: Hey Avery, the query you posted give the same results. The issue is that 3, 'A', 2 is not being excluded. This is exactly why I'm confused - the commented out where not exists clause does the same thing your lag clause is supposed to do.. neither is working. You can reference the second CTE for accurate results. I'll add a sql fiddle.

Comment: SQL fiddle added to main post.

Comment: My output is not the same.  The rest.columns are null for 3 A 2.  If you wanted to exclude them entirely, then the rest.val <> main.prevVal needs to be moved to a where clause instead of the left join criteria.

Comment: Hey Avery, oh okay- yeah, I was looking to exclude them and didn't realize the difference. Thanks for the clarification!